# Custom JRE with Java EE(Jakarta)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

After added the great feature of Java Module that can run custom JRE for specific application developed and Jakarta for develop the web application or enterprise application which can run Jakarta 9 , I can't understanding method to create web application with java! the question is if I need java 11(or 8) to create web application and Jakarta 9 do I need the Custom JRE that create with module ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is no required. Actually, the spec is silent in the way or application is deployed.
Currently, there is no more concept of JRE, using newer JDKs, only JLinked images, where you can select only the modules you need.
For now, only Java 8 is supported officially, with support for Java 11 coming shortly.

The specification doesn't mention anything about the Java module system. However, if you want to use modules, you could that a look at the Piranha Cloud project.

https://piranha.cloud

[Disclaimer: Piranha Cloud developer here]